# Ionic 3 show cancel text instead of cancel icon in search Bar

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

[image]I have this code for searchbar in my ionic 3 app but i cant seem to change the x button to a text .there is this input property cancelButtonText
in ionic documentation but i dont know how to apply this.
The x button at the end of the search bar ,i have to change it to a text like clear instead of x.

```
 <ion-searchbar
  [(ngModel)]="myInput"
  [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel"
  (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
  (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">

</ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: Can you give more info about your issue? It is not clear for me. Maybe you can provide an image of your UI. Give all the info you have.Otherwise, you cannot get feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding cancelButtonText property like this?:

```
<ion-searchbar
  [(ngModel)]="myInput"
  [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel"
  (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
  (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)"
  [cancelButtonText]="YOUR_TEXT_HERE">
</ion-searchbar>
```

It also seems to only work this way on iOS devices, see: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/

This code seems to be working on an iOS device:

```
<ion-searchbar showCancelButton="true" cancelButtonText="xxx"></ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: yes i have tried that but unfortunately its not working.

Comment: I tested it a couple of times on my own machine, and as far as I can tell the cancelButtonText only works on iOS devices. I'd suggest you head over to the [Ionic forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/), maybe they can be of assistance